# Codeigniter 3.0.0 file helper litterally writes \n

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to log some user activity in a file, like one activity per line

I am using the file helper in order to do so

```php
$this->load->helper('file');
$logline = '[' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s.v') . '] ' . $data['user_id'] . ' | ' . $data['activity'] . '\n';
$logpath = './application/logs/application_activity.log';
return write_file($logpath, $logline, 'a+');
```

And in my output file, it litterally writes the `\n` at the end of the line, like this

```
[2022-03-03 08:49:26.000] Super Administrateur | Validated citizen 1195078 as duplicate\n
```

How to just make it create a new line at the end of the file?

Side note: if you know where it would be more appropriate to write the logs, please be me guest

Comment: You're using single quotes around `'\n'` whereas you intend to use double quotes `"\n"`. See: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: it was the single quote
now I learned something thanks to your link